# MySql ORDER BY FIELD() in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a list of numbers and need to select rows from DB table by that order.
i was looking to implement `ORDER BY FIELD()` query in LinQ / lambda expressions with no luck

any ideas?

the code look like this:

```
 using (var db = new TimeTable.EntityFramework.TimeTableEntities())
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>() { 2, 1, 4, 3 };
            var query = db.place_users_info.OrderBy(item => item.UniqueId);
        }
```

I need to order the rows by the list items

Comment: if it isn't that big amount of data , just enumerate and order after the data has been retrived

Comment: thanks, how can order the data by the list?

Comment: can you share your EF query code ?

Comment: Could be the same of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349413/how-to-get-records-from-tables-in-custom-order-of-ids/39357035#39364400

Answer (score 1):

if your rowcount is not that big, maybe you are looking for something like this (checks ommitted):

```
using (var db = new TimeTable.EntityFramework.TimeTableEntities())
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>() { 2, 1, 4, 3 };
            var a = db.place_users_info.ToArray();
            var b = list.Select(x=>a[x]).ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you have (according to the example) 4 rows which you want to order by the number they have on the number list.

To do so use `Zip` to merge the lists by index (first item in numbers list will be with first item in the data list and so on)

```
using (var db = new TimeTable.EntityFramework.TimeTableEntities())
{ 
    List<int> list = new List<int>() { 2, 1, 4, 3 }; 
    var query = db.place_users_info.Zip(list, (f,s) => new { f,s })
                                   .OrderBy(item => item.s)
                                   .Select(item => item.f); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the list, say:

```
var list<myobject> = <yourRepository>.<GetYourData>.ToList().OrderBy(o => o.<property>;
```

besides, in memory order by is probably faster then in DB.

If you would do:

```
var list<myobject> = <yourRepository>.<GetYourData>.OrderBy(o => o.<property>).ToList();
```

you would do the order by in the DB. (If your  returns an IQueryable)